# Is my question innapropriate to the site? Why is it likely to be voted down?

Tags: discussion

I just got a question ([Hotel keycard switches on 5,000W load when placed in its holder. How does it do that?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/92685/29792)) voted down. I know the question isn't a blockbuster, but the comments I got have already been helpful to me. So, I'm a bit confused.

**What would be the likely reasons for the votedown?** I wanted to know so that my next questions are better formulated and I can make better use of the EE.SE network in the future.

Comment: I don't know why.  I just voted it up.

Comment: Thank you all for the great advice. I'll follow your suggestions in my next posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't actually downvote that question of yours.  But, I can point out a few things that can rub the wrong way.

- The title of the question refers to a piece of consumer electronics: hotel key chain.  It would be better if you've removed that reference from the title, replaced it with your 5,000W estimate, and backed it up with your story about the hotel key chain in the body of the question.
- You are asking about a "*link to actual devices or datasheet*" from the start.  This hints at a [chronic] lack of research effort.  A better approach is to receive some comments or answers, do a bit of searching on your own.  Then ask more pointed questions

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful advice. I'll fix the title ASAP. As for the request for links and datasheets, I was trying to avoid trivial answers like "use a relay." I was looking for examples of devices that would actually handle the load.

Comment: @Ricardo The right way to avoid *trivial answers like "use a relay"* is to cover, in the body of the question, what you have already found out, and why such options do not suit the purpose. That is a comment you will often find in insufficiently specified questions on this site: "*Tell us what you have found out so far and what the specific problem is*".

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I just commented on in the question:

> @Ricardo the question does show a lack of research and vagueness. Keycard vs keychain as original listed, no model numbers or even pictures, which is asking us to guess at a possible method it is working by, which makes it open ended. If you said "How does Model X (part number: yyyzzz) Keycard Switch work? I have looked for a schematic or datasheet but can't find one. It does X, Y and Z" that would draw less negative attention.

Asking for essentially Educated guesses are not really conductive to the site, or to you as the asker. We have very little information to work on. And I didn't downvote it either.

As for what we mean by like to actual devices or datasheet, WE mean that you should be providing that for the part you need to understand. Like a manufacturer and model number of the key card switch.